# Get event of screen load on Stack.Navigator in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way to get screen load events in `Stack.Navigator`
I want to get the name of the screen loaded in the stack navigator itself where we create stacks using createStackNavigator()

Answer (score 0):

There is a `state` event emitted on navigation when the navigator's state changes. You can add a ref to `NavigationContainer` and listen for `state` event on `ref.current` inside `componentDidMount`.